# passing php variables from dynamically created HTML Document

Tags: php, html, dom

How to pass the php variables from dynamically created HTML page to next php file.
For Example. I have the following php code

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $uid=$_SESSION['uid'];
 $doc=new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->loadHTML("
                     <html>
                    <head>
                    </head>
                  <body>
                  <a href='comments.php?id=`$uid`'> comments</a>
                  </body>   
                  </html>
               ");
     echo 'wrote:'. $doc->savedHTMLFile("/home/user/project1/test1.html"). 'bytes';

?>
```

Now when I see dynamically created HTML page, it just shows me the following code with .html extension; so how can I pass the php variable from this page to next file:

```
                    <html>
                    <head>
                    </head>
                  <body>
                  <a href='comments.php?id=`$uid`'> comments</a>
                  </body>   
                  </html>
```

Comment: dynamically created page has .HTML extenstion; so is it possible to pass a php variable from HTML page? and how to make changes to make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this... Your mistake is here `'comments.php?id=`$uid`'` is string no php code use correct like this `'comments.php?id=".$uid."'`.

```
<?php
session_start();
$uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->loadHTML("
                <html>
                <head>
                </head>
                  <body>
                  <a href='comments.php?id=".$uid."'> comments</a>
                  </body>
                  </html>
               ");
echo 'wrote:' . $doc->savedHTMLFile("/home/user/project1/test1.html") . 'bytes';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to replace

```
<a href='comments.php?id=`$uid`'>
```

to

```
<a href='comments.php?id=$uid'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can use $_GET[''] method to do it. You just insert it into the URL, but I think, this will make the site vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

remove back ticks(`) around $uid or use this code

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $uid=$_SESSION['uid'];
 $doc=new DOMDocument('1.0');
 $doc->loadHTML("
                     <html>
                    <head>
                    </head>
                  <body>
                  <a href='comments.php?id=".$uid."> comments</a>
                  </body>   
                  </html>
               ");
     echo 'wrote:'. $doc->savedHTMLFile("/home/user/project1/test1.html"). 'bytes';

?>
```